# How to get fractional labels with psaxes?

Tags: pstricks, pst-plot

The objective is to get fractional labels (not in decimal) for both vertical and horizontal axes.

In my experience, non-trigonometric labels are written in decimals and trigonometric labels can be written in fractional via `trigLabels` and `trigLabelBase`. I attempted to abuse these keys to get fractional non-trigonometric by using `\let\pi=\relax`, but it causes a problem where

- `\pi/n` becomes `/n` (that should be `1/n`),
- `-\pi/n` becomes `-/n` (that should be `-1/n`),
- `-\pi` becomes `-` (that should be `-1`),
- `\pi` becomes `<empty>` (that should be `1`) where `<empty>` stands for empty .

My question, what is the best trick to convert every `\pi` to `relax` but prevent the problems from happening?

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

\FPeval\XMin{0-2}
\FPeval\XMax{2}
\FPeval\YMin{0-1}
\FPeval\YMax{1}
\FPeval\temp{1/3}

\psset
{
    ytrigLabels=true,
    xtrigLabels=true,
    trigLabelBase=3,
    unit=3cm,
}

\let\pi=\relax

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(\XMin,\YMin)(\XMax,\YMax)
    \psaxes[dx=\temp,dy=\temp](0,0)(\XMin,\YMin)(\XMax,\YMax)
    \psplot[algebraic,plotpoints=100]{\XMin}{\XMax}{x-2/3}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### More general case

Sometimes I need to change `\pi` to `\sqrt{2}`, for example. I tried with

```
\let\pi={\sqrt{2}}
```

but it does not compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version 1.71 from http://texnik.dante.de/tex/generic/pst-plot/
knows `fractionLabel`:

```
\errorcontextlines=100
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\psset{fractionLabels,fractionLabelBase=3,unit=3cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-1)(2,1)
    \psaxes[dx=0.333,dy=0.333](0,0)(-2,-1)(2,1)
    \psplot[algebraic,plotpoints=100]{-2}{2}{x-2/3}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

However, there is a spurious space which needs some more investigation.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, is it possible to change `\pi` with `e`, `\sqrt{m}`, etc such that we can have `\frac{e}{n}`, `\frac{\sqrt{m}}{n}`, etc where `n` is the `fractionLabelBase`?

Comment: for example: `xlabelFactor=\sqrt{2}` or `\def\pi{e}`

Comment: Sorry. Using `xlabelFactor` makes the factor appear on the right of the fractional labels rather than in the numerator of the fractional labels. As a result, there are some "oddities" such as `-1\sqrt{2}` and `1\sqrt{2}`. It will be better if we can change `\pi` in the numerator with `\sqrt{2}`, for example.

Comment: `\def\pi{\sqrt{2}}` for example

Comment: The update of `pst-plot` was done on August 24 but up to now it has not been propagated to TeXLive mirrors. A weird thing happened: `pst-poly` updated on August 28 has been propagated to TeXLive mirrors.